# SQL CFoutput help, not processing when opening webpage

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion

I am currently learning SQL. On my CFM page I have entered all the information from the instructions my professor has given us. I have even compared to other students to try and figure out what is wrong, but their pages look like mine. Please help me figure out what I have done wrong. Thanks.

This is the webpage link http://pretendcompany.com/jaedenemployees.html

**Error:**

> 72777A, on line 66, column 32, is not a valid identifer name. The CFML
>   compiler was processing: The body of a CFOUTPUT tag beginning on line
>   62, column 3.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<meta name="author" content="YOUR NAME HERE" />

<title>USU MIS 2100</title>

<style type="text/css" media="all">
td {
align:center;
width:955;
border:none;
text-align:center;  
vertical-align:top;
height:40px;
}


table.center{
    margin:auto;
}
h1{
font-size:26px;
color:#001F3E;  

}
h2{
font-size:20px; 
color:#ffffff;
}
img{ text-align:center;
}
td.photo{
margin:auto;    

}
</style>


</head>

<body>
<table class="center">
  <tr>
    <td  ><img src="images/header2_usu.jpg" width="755" height="265" alt="usu" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:900;background-color:#D7D9D9;padding-top:50px;">

    Employees by Department at Pretend Company, Inc.</font></p>
      <h1>Jaeden Harris</h1>

 <CFQUERY name="jaeden" datasource="employeedatasource">
 select Accounting,Administrative,Advertising,Payroll,Sales
 from employees
where DepartmentName in(#PreserveSingleQuotes(form.SelectDepts)#)
 </CFQUERY>

     <!--Place opening CFOUTPUT here -->
 <CFOUTPUT query="jaeden">


<table style="width:500;border:none;" class="center">
  <tr style="background-color:#72777A;">
    <td colspan="2"><h2> #DepartmentName# Employees </h2></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:250;text-align:left;">Employee:#FirstName# #MiddleName# #LastName#  
          <p>Title: #Title#
          <p>Email: #EmailName# @pretendcompany.com
          <p>Contact Number: #WorkPhone#

      </p>
      </td>
    <td style="width:140px;vertical-align:middle;" class="photo"><!--Reference Photograph field here -->      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
 </CFOUTPUT>


     </td>
  </tr>
      </table>


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You page is a HTML file, not CFM. I would start there.

Comment: thanks for your concern I downloaded it exactly how she gave us the base file, and have been editing with notepad++ it has a CFM extension.

Comment: What's not processing? Is the query not being executed? Errors within the cfoutput tags?

Comment: 72777A, on line 66, column 32, is not a valid identifer name.

The CFML compiler was processing:

The body of a CFOUTPUT tag beginning on line 62, column 3.

Comment: Administrative Error when trying to execute my field names to the CFM file.

Comment: You are within a CFOUTPUT, therefor anything with # signs gets evaluated, including the style `background-color:#72777A;`. Either escape those with a double hash: `background-color:##72777A;` or move the style out of your CFOUTPUT.

Comment: Contrary to what your teacher may have told you, I emphasize functionality over form.  In other words, I get all my data and other programming code working first, and worry about display code afterwards.  In the case of this question, I see a subject line and problem description about sql and cfml, and then a bunch of css.  I stopped reading.  Too much chaff hiding the wheat.

Comment: If you are new to CF, you may want to read [Using pound signs # in ColdFusion](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Using+number+signs).

Answer (score 6):

You are within a CFOUTPUT, therefor anything with # signs gets evaluated, including the style `background-color:#72777A;`. Either escape those with a double hash: `background-color:##72777A;` or move the style out of your CFOUTPUT.

Since you already have a section for your CSS, it may be wise for you to move all your table styles from inline with the HTML to the top and just apply classes to your elements.

Comment: Ok great that definitely helped but now i'm getting the error:

Comment: Error Executing Database Query.

[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 5.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax for MS Access. My initial assumption would be there an error in your `IN ()` clause. Does `form.SelectDepts` have a value?

Comment: i might be well off here, but i'm sure that error means you've got a database field name incorrect in your query, in this case 5 of them wrong!

Comment: That is a definite possibility. Another is the `IN (#PreserveSingleQuotes(form.SelectDepts)#)` clause.  If the individual values *inside* the field are not quoted - ie ABC,EDF instead of 'ABC','EDF', ...  Access will probably think they are object names, which would likely cause the same error.  That said, using `PreserveSingleQuotes` is a bad practice.  Instead you should use <cfqueryparam> with the "list" attribute.  @JaedenHarris -  S.O. is different than a discussion forum. As your original question was answered, you should post a separate question about the new SQL error.